# Unclear IDE warning for getFusedLocationClient in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, lint

I'm getting the following IDE warning for my code in *Android Studio*:

> Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with checkPermission) or explicitly handle a potential SecurityException

My code looks like this. It's supposed to set a `GoogleMap` object to show a frame with the user's location normally, and a frame with all of Germany if they have location disabled (`location == null`) or denied location permissions for the app (`addOnFailureListener`).

```
fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnFailureListener(this) {
    Log.e("onRequestPermissions", "fail")
    mMap?.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(51.17, 10.45), 6F))  // Germany
}

fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener(this) { location ->
    Log.e("onRequestPermissions", "succ")
    if (location == null)
        mMap?.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(51.17, 10.45), 6F))  // Germany
    else
        mMap?.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude), 13F))
}
```

I don't get why calling `fusedLocationClient` (`getFusedLocationClient`) gives me this error message. I thought the `FusedLocationProviderClient` was always there, and I'm handling the case that the user denied location permission **inside of `addOnFailureListener`**. So how can I possibly attach this failure callback if I'm not allowed to even call `getFusedLocationClient`.

This warning is treated with severity "error" and all-red text by Android Studio which makes my code look pretty broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to let *Lint* know you are "aware of the corresponding permission check and handle it somewhere else in your code" add the `@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")` annotation to the method which contains the code.

The [@SuppressLint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/annotation/SuppressLint) annotation

> Indicates that Lint should ignore the specified warnings for the annotated element.

Comment: @xjcl, in the code you've posted you are not doing a permission check. Please, see [Request app permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) for more info on this.

Answer (score 2):

The error is actually asking you should either explicitly check whether requested permission is enabled or you can disable lint checking by adding the @SuppressLint annotation to that code.

```
PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED ==
                        PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(
                            requireContext(),
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                        ))
```

Or

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
```